# How to reset textbox values in dialog after destroy?

Tags: jquery

I have a dialog in which there are 2 textboxes.  I want to reset the textboxes values once the dialog is destroyed. How can I do that?

If I have entered values in the textboxes and clicked cancel, reopening the dialog will show the data entered previously.

```
function setDialogWindows($element) {
      $('#change').dialog({    
           autoOpen: true,    
           width: 380,    
           buttons: {   
              "Cancel": function() {    
                   $(this).dialog('destroy');   
              },    
              "Accept": function() {    
              } 
     }): 
 }
```

---

```
$('#link').click(function() {    
    setDialogWindows('#change');    
});
```

---

```
<div id="change" title="Change password" >
    <input type="hidden" id="User_Name" name="Name"/>    
    <input type="textbox" id="text1" />
    <input type="textbox" id="text2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

At first, type `textbox` does not exist. Use `text` or `password` (for masked characters) instead.

Use this code to clean the inputs:

```
"Accept": function() {    
    $("#text1").val('');
    $("#text2").val('');
}
```

---

Finally, I've rewritten the code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Show me a dialog!</a>
<div id="change" title="Change password">
    <input type="hidden" id="User_Name" name="Name"/>    
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    <input type="text" id="text2"/>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#link').click(function() {    
    setDialogWindows();    
});

function setDialogWindows() {
    $('#change').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 380,    
        buttons: {   
            "Cancel": function() {    
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },    
            "Accept": function() {
                /* Place your handler here. */
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
                $("#text1").val('');
                $("#text2").val('');
        }
   });
}
```

You can use `$(this).dialog('destroy');` with `"Cancel"` button, but it will not modify yout `input` fields as they are declared independently from the dialog. That's why you ought to clean them manually.

Comment: Are the textboxes not supposed to be empty after the destroy and when reopening the dialog?

Comment: @user281180, no. Destroying just *hides* the dialog.

Comment: What is the difference between closing and destroying? I want to reset the controls in the dialog when re-opening, how can I achieve that, without writing any other code? Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've messed up with it. Destroying **should** clear inputs — i.e. destroying will return the element back to its pre-init state

Comment: I`m confused.  I`m using destroy, still I have to clear the text values before closing?

Comment: If I use only $(this).dialog('destroy');, then next time the dialog doesn`t reopen again! That`s why I had wtitten the above code.

Comment: @user281180 Try modified version, please.

Answer (score 3):

Clear all dialog's data before close it.
Here is the code:

```
function setDialogWindows($element) {
      $('#change').dialog({    
           autoOpen: true,
           beforeClose: function (event, ui) { $(this).empty(); },    
           width: 380,    
           buttons: {   
              "Cancel": function() {    
                   $(this).dialog('destroy');   
              },    
              "Accept": function() {    
              } 
     }): 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
"Cancel": function() {
    $(':text',this).val('');    
    $(this).dialog('destroy');   
}
```

and also I notice, you missed 1 `}` on `buttons :{}` and `<input type="textbox" id="text1" />` should be `<input type="text" id="text2" />`. notice the type...

**edit**

when you want to reset text boxes on re-open, don't need to destroy it...

```
$( "#change" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui).find(':text').val('');
   },
   autoOpen: true,    
   width: 380,    
   buttons: {   
      "Cancel": function() {    
            $(this).dialog('destroy');   
       },    
       "Accept": function() {    
       } 
   }
});
```